# what is FB.Arbiter.inform?

Tags: javascript, facebook

what exactly does **FB.Arbiter** object inside the **"connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js**"?

is it something for communication between iframes? there is a **inform** function inside **FB.Arbiter** which creates an invisible iframe inside iframe app.

this is the source of inform function:

```
function (d, f, g, c, a) 
{
    if (FB.Canvas.isTabIframe() || FB._inPlugin && window.postMessage || !FB._inCanvas && FB.UA.mobile() && window.postMessage) 
    {
        var e = FB.JSON.stringify({
            method : d, params : f, behavior : a || FB.Arbiter.BEHAVIOR_PERSISTENT
        });
        if (window.postMessage) {
            FB.XD.resolveRelation(g || "parent").postMessage(e, "*");
            return;
        }
        else {
            try {
                window.opener.postMessage(e);
                return;
            }
            catch (b) { }
        }
    }
    var i = FB.getDomain((c ? "https_" : "") + "staticfb") + FB.Arbiter._canvasProxyUrl + "#" + FB.QS.encode(
    {
        method : d, params : FB.JSON.stringify(f || {}), behavior : a || FB.Arbiter.BEHAVIOR_PERSISTENT, 
        relation : g
    });
    var h = FB.Content.appendHidden("");
    FB.Content.insertIframe(
    {
        url : i, root : h, width : 1, height : 1,
        onload : function () 
        {
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                h.parentNode.removeChild(h);
            }, 10);
        }
    });
}
```

can someone explain this function?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has a class called `Arbiter` that manages events. It's basically Facebook's own event system. You can bind a function to an event using `Arbiter.subscribe("id/id",function_name)`. `"id/id"` is just a string that identifies a custom name for an event. When you call `Arbiter.inform("id/id",{data:"in an object"})`, any functions that were subscribed using the same `"id/id"`, such as `function_name()`, are called, and `{data:"in an object"}` is passed to it as the second argument. (The first argument is just `"id/id"`.)

In other words, `Arbiter.inform()` triggers events in Facebook's event system.

Comment: great explanation, thanks! Do you know if there is a simple way to log all facebook events that are sent to the Arbiter system?

Comment: @user280109 I don't know off the top of my head whether you can simply `Arbiter.subscribe("*/*", my_function)` or not. You could try, perhaps. Another way to go about it would be to hijack the `Arbiter.inform()` function, like so: `var Arbi = Arbiter.inform; Arbiter.inform = function(id, data){console.log(id, data); Arbi(id, data);}`

Comment: thanks so much for that code, it used to work great (a few years ago). But they seem to have changed their system now, and when i try it now, i get the following error message:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: Arbiter is not defined" 

any idea on how to get this functionality back again?